# Digit-by-digit addition using vectors

Tags: c++

I was asked to perform addition by using vectors, so I am wondering if the function I coded looks good. If not, how can I improve the quality of my code? Below, I provided .h and .cpp files. I need feedback on the string constructor and operator+ modules.

.h file

```
class ubigint {
   friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const ubigint&);
   private:
      /*using unumber = unsigned long;
      unumber uvalue {};
      */
      using udigit_t = unsigned char; 
      using ubigvalue_t = vector<udigit_t>; 
      ubigvalue_t ubig_value; 

   public:
      void multiply_by_2();
      void divide_by_2();

      ubigint() = default; // Need default ctor as well.
      ubigint (unsigned long);
      ubigint (const string&);

      ubigint operator+ (const ubigint&) const;
      ubigint operator- (const ubigint&) const;
      ubigint operator* (const ubigint&) const;
      ubigint operator/ (const ubigint&) const;
      ubigint operator% (const ubigint&) const;

      bool operator== (const ubigint&) const;
      bool operator<  (const ubigint&) const;
};
```

Currently, I am just done with the constructor and operator+. I feel like my function needs a little improvement since I seem to be repetitive in some places; however, a lot of people may say that the exhaustive creation of modules may lead to poor performance. I just tried to keep my code clean, but I don't know if the quality is good. I neither have checked if the code runs since I have to do other stuff in order to do so.
.cpp file

```
ubigint::ubigint (const string& that){
   DEBUGF ('~', "that = \"" << that << "\"");
   for (char digit: that) {
      if (not isdigit (digit)) {
         throw invalid_argument ("ubigint::ubigint(" + that + ")");
      }
   }

   for(string::reverse_iterator rit = that.str().rbegin(); rit != that.str().rend(); rit++) // iterate the string from end to start and store it in the vector
    {
        ubig_value.push_back(*rit); // push the character
    }  

}



 ubigint ubigint::operator+ (const ubigint& that) const {  //modify to handle vector wise addition

    int carry = 0;  // current carrier
    int counter = 0;  
    int pairAdditionResult = 0;
    int vectorValue = 0;
    udigit_t vectorCharValue = '0';
    ubigvalue_t result;

    do{
        pairAdditionResult = (ubig_value[counter] -'0') + (that[counter] - '0') + carry;
        carry = pairAdditionResult / 10;
        vectorValue = pairAdditionResult % 10;
        vectorCharValue = vectorValue + '0';
        result.push_back(vectorCharValue);
        counter++;

    }while(counter != ubig_value.size() && counter != that.size())

    if(ubig_value.size() != counter )  // if the size of the vectors differ
    {
        do{
          pairAdditionResult = (ubig_value[counter] - '0') + carry;
          carry = pairAdditionResult / 10;
          vectorValue = pairAdditionResult % 10;
          vectorCharValue = vectorValue  + '0';
          result.push_back(vectorCharValue);
          counter++;

        }while(counter != ubig_value.size())

    }
    else if (that.size() != counter)
    {
        do{
            pairAdditionResult =(that[counter] - '0') + carry;
            carry = pairAdditionResult / 10;
            vectorValue = pairAdditionResult % 10;
            vectorCharValue = vectorValue + '0';
            result.push_back(vectorCharValue);
            counter++;
        }while(counter != that.size(counter != that.size()))

    }

    if(carry != 0)  // for the last digit of the result
    {
        result.push_back(carry + '0');
    }

    int resultVectorSize = result.size();   
    string resultVectorString;  // used for passing the number as a string in the returned object
    while(resultVectorSize != 0)
    {
        resultVectorString.push_back(result[resultVectorSize-1])
        resultVectorSize--;
    }

   return ubigint (resultVectorString);
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as the code provided has compilation errors beyond omitting `#include`s and therefore is not ready for review.

Answer (score 2):

1. I'm not sure whether you used `using namespace std;` in the header, or only committed the lesser evil of needlessly importing many names into the global namespace in a header. Anyway, as you are implementing some new library-code, open your own namespace and confine your code to it.
   Please read [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

Let's take a look at your data-structure:

2. You are using a `std::vector`, so you have its re-allocation-behavior of roughly doubling the space on demand, and keeping the maximum ever reserved. Not a bad choice.
3. You store your number as single digit characters. That's workable, but you should really think about storing `0` as `0` not `'0'`. It makes math easier. Still, I'll keep with that.
4. Binary operators should, for those where the language allows it, be free functions or at least `friend`-functions to reduce coupling and enable conversion on the left hand side.
   That holds even if you later add overloads to remove those conversions for efficiency.
5. If you provide some binary operator, it's convenient and customary to also provide the corresponding compound-assignment-operator.

And now your interface:

6. A conversion (single-argument-ctor or `operator Type`) should only be implicit if it is lossless and is expected to succeed for all valid inputs.
   But `"A"` is a valid string but will not be accepted.
7. Use `std::string_view` instead of constant reference to `std::string` as input. Thus the caller isn't forced to use a `std::string` with the possible dynamic allocation (and copy) that entails.

Let's take a look at your ctor:

8. How does `DEBUGF` work? Maybe it's a debug-tracing-macro, but what's the first argument for then? Oh well, it's not that important.
9. You know exactly how long the input is, so why don't you `.reserve()` space for it to avoid reallocations?
10. You know calling `std::isdigit()` with a negative value `!= EOF` is undefined behavior? Cast to `unsigned char` first!
11. You optimized your ctor for bad input, as you do a first pass solely to verify the input, and then a second pass to finally store it. Combine the passes into one.
12. You should probably eliminate leading zeroes. That also makes everything easier.

```
ubigint::ubigint(std::string_view that) {
    auto pos = that.find_first_not_of('0');
    if(pos != that.npos)
        that = that.substr(pos);

    ubig_value.reserve(that.size());

    for(auto it = rbegin(that); it != rend(that); ++it) {
        if(!isdigit((unsigned char)*it))
            throw invalid_argument ("ubigint::ubigint(" + that + ")");
        ubig_value.push_back((unsigned char)*it);
    }
}
```

Now, your addition:

13. While it is often recommended to implement `operator+` as a free function in terms of `operator+=` to avoid repetition, your class doesn't qualify, as it would result in (maybe severe) loss of efficiency. You might want to do it the other way around instead.
14. Still, that doesn't mean that your try is good. Your first loop repeatedly tests both inputs lengths. Why don't you use `std::max(a, b)`?
15. You are using `/` and `%` to calculate the carry and the value. While it works, it's highly inefficient. You know the carry is at most one, so use an `if`-statement and subtraction.
16. Point 2 comes back to bite you there. See how biasing the numbers with `'0'` creeps everywhere into the calculations?
17. The following `if`-`else if`-statement is just painful. You are doing the same for both cases, just with a different input-variable. Merge that.
18. The end really gets me scratching my head. Why do you convert the perfectly usable `ubigint` into a `std::string` and then back on returning?
19. I haven't seen `.size()` and `operator[]` in your interface, but adding them is a good idea, so I pretend you already did so. You might want to overhaul your data-structure first though, to be `0` instead of `'0'`-based.

```
ubigint operator+ (const ubigint& a, const ubigint& b) {
    if(a.size() > b.size())
        return b + a;

    bool carry = false;
    ubigint result;
    result.reserve(b.size() + 1);
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for(; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        auto c = a[i] + b[i] + carry - '0';
        if(c <= '9') {
            carry = false;
        } else {
            c -= 10;
            carry = true;
        }
        result.push_back(c);
    }

    while(carry && i < b.size()) {
        auto c = b[i] + carry;
        if(c <= '9')
            carry = false;
        else
            c -= 10;
        result.ubig_value.push_back(c);
    }

    if(!carry)
        std::copy(b.begin() + i, b.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
    else
        result.ubig_value.push_back(c);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: And it would be easy to add another suggestion:
20. Declare variables when they are used. A few variables like `pairAdditionResult` should be inside the loop as there are not used outside of the loop and they don't have run-time overhead.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to implement `operator+` as a `friend`:

```
friend ubigint operator+(ubigint lhs, const ubigint& rhs);
```

It is also recommended to implement it in terms of `operator+=`:

```
friend ubigint operator+(ubigint lhs, const ubigint& rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

For details, see [Canonical Implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators)

---

The `operator+=` can be made very simple. You only need to extend the `ubig_value` with zeroes to match the length of other, then just apply your loop once (and push the remaining carry if necessary).

---

I also recommend to convert characters to digits in the constructor.

Comment: Why declare `operator+()` as a friend, and not as a non-friend non-member?  It doesn't need access to anything other than the public `operator+=()` method.

Comment: @TobySpeight and vnp: Actually, implementing `+` using `+=` is a big waste, twice the allocations in half the cases, and lhs.size() additional bytes copied.

Comment: @Deduplicator, that's true, but let's start with "correct" before optimising!

Answer (score 1):

## Don't re-provide `std` names in your namespace

You don't show your complete header, but it appears that you have something like

```
#include <iosfwd>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::invalid_argument;
using std::ostream;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
```

Never import names not implemented by you into the global namespace.  Instead, write them out in full in your header.

In your implementation file, the `using` lines are less dangerous, but I'd still advise you not to import names at file scope, just to avoid surprises.

## Fix the blatant bugs

Before posting code for review, always ask your compiler for its own review.  Doing so highlights these errors:

```
error: ‘const string {aka const class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ has no member named ‘str’
    for(std::string::reverse_iterator rit = that.str().rbegin(); rit != that.str().rend(); rit++) // iterate the string from end to start and store it in the vector
                                                 ^~~
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘const ubigint’ and ‘int’)
         pairAdditionResult = (ubig_value[counter] -'0') + (that[counter] - '0') + carry;
error: ‘const class ubigint’ has no member named ‘size’
     }while(counter != ubig_value.size() && counter != that.size())
                                                            ^~~~
error: ‘const class ubigint’ has no member named ‘size’
     else if (that.size() != counter)
                   ^~~~
error: ‘const class ubigint’ has no member named ‘size’
         }while(counter != that.size(counter != that.size()))
                                ^~~~
error: ‘const class ubigint’ has no member named ‘size’
         }while(counter != that.size(counter != that.size()))
                                                     ^~~~
```

as well as numerous syntax errors, mostly caused by omitted `;`.

Furthermore, it also advises:

```
warning: ‘ubigint::ubig_value’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
 ubigint::ubigint (const std::string& that)
 ^~~~~~~
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     }while(counter != ubig_value.size() && counter != that.size())
            ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

## Constructor

You probably want to declare the the constructor from `std::string` to be `explicit`, as it's surprising to to have string types implicitly convert to something that doesn't behave at all like a string.  Implicit conversion is more reasonable from unsigned integral types, as this is a number-like class.

You can make the constructor more efficient by telling the vector how big it will need to be, in advance of populating it:

```
ubig_value.reserve(that.size());
```

It's probably better to make a single pass over the input string, and check the digits as you add them (the exception should be a rare case, and this saves work for the common case):

```
ubigint::ubigint(const std::string& that)
    : ubig_value{}
{
    ubig_value.reserve(that.size());
    for (auto i = that.rbegin();  i != that.rend();  ++i) {
        if (!isdigit(*i))
            throw std::invalid_argument("ubigint::ubigint(" + that + ")");
        ubig_value.push_back(*i - '0');
    }
}
```

In the above, I've reduced the `char` values by `'0'` to get the `unsigned char` for the vector.  This will make arithmetic slightly more efficient, at a small cost to conversions to/from strings.  More importantly, it reduces clutter in the code and makes it easier to understand (*is this `unsigned char` a character or a number?*).

## Addition

The addition algorithm has a bug if either summand is default-constructed or otherwise empty, because the loop is `do`-`while` rather than `while`-`do`.  The loop will iterate at least once, dereferencing `ubig_value[0]` even if it has no right to do so.

You can simplify the logic by zero-extending the arguments before summing, so you don't need to repeat the per-digit code three times.

---

## Worked example

Here's some working code, with tests to demonstrate:

```
#include <iosfwd>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class ubigint
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const ubigint&);

    std::vector<unsigned char> value;     // least-significant first

public:
    explicit ubigint(const std::string& = {});

    ubigint& operator+= (const ubigint&);
};
```

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>

ubigint::ubigint(const std::string& s)
    : value{}
{
    value.reserve(s.size());
    for (auto i = s.rbegin();  i != s.rend();  ++i) {
        if (!std::isdigit(*i))
            throw std::invalid_argument("ubigint(" + s + ")");
        value.push_back(*i - '0');
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ubigint& v)
{
    if (v.value.empty())
        return os << '0';

    for (auto i = v.value.rbegin();  i != v.value.rend();  ++i)
        os << char('0' + *i);
    return os;
}


ubigint& ubigint::operator+=(const ubigint& other)
{
    value.reserve(std::max(value.size(), other.value.size()) + 1);

    if (value.size() < other.value.size()) {
        // zero-extend to make enough space - allow 1 extra digit in case of carry
        value.reserve(other.value.size() + 1);
        std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(value), other.value.size()-value.size(), 0);
    }

    unsigned char carry = 0;
    for (auto i = 0u;  i < value.size();  ++i) {
        auto digit = value[i] + carry;
        if (i < other.value.size())
            digit += other.value[i];
        carry = digit >= 10;
        if (carry)
            digit -= 10;
        value[i] = digit;
    }
    if (carry)
        value.push_back(carry);

    return *this;
}

ubigint operator+(ubigint first, const ubigint& second)
{
    return first += second;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    ubigint v;
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    v += ubigint("98");
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    v += ubigint("7");
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    v += ubigint("900");
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    std::cout << ubigint("7")+ubigint("98") << std::endl;
}
```